# Nginx: Conditional request gunzip when `Content-Encoding: gzip` is set

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, gzip

How would it be possible in nginx to evaluate if the `Content-Encoding: gzip` **request header** is set (coming from a web client to nginx), and then let nginx `gunzip` the request before it gets forwarded to an upstream (e.g. fastcgi)?

Comment: have you tried `if ( $content_encoding = 'gzip') { gunzip on; }`

Comment: @DavidParlevliet I think the `if` condition is redundant.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that `gunzip` is only decompressing `responses`, not the incoming `requests` from a web client (I refined my question a bit). How could I nginx unzip a web request before it gets forwarded to an, e.g. fastcgi, upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research it seems decompressing requests is not possible out of the box. Using LUA like described here is unfortunately not something I want to do: http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html#.VrCv87IrKHt.

Seems like I'd have to handle the decompression in my backend server code :/